# why my bot is not dending the image in embed

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

```
const { MessageEmbed, WebhookClient, GuildMember} = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
    name : 'guildMemberAdd',
    /**
     * 
     * @param {GuildMember} member 
     */
    async execute(member) {
        const {guild, user} = member;

        const welcomer = new WebhookClient({
            id : '958046742446759936',
            token: '3X9d1gJT8rLCyV-WFkorfkpU5Tl9iF8IXWMz3BOfuR7GQ1Sf5V5OD1HwWxRHRLf97tK0'
        });

        const welcome = new MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('AQUA')
        .setAuthor({name: user.tag,iconURL: user.avatarURL({dynamic:true})})
        .setThumbnail(user.avatarURL)
        .setDescription(`Welcome ${member} to the **${guild.name}**!\nAccount Created: <t:${parseInt(user.createdTimestamp/1000)}:R>\nLatest Member Count: **${guild.memberCount}**`)
        .setFooter({
            text: user.tag,
            iconURL: user.avatarURL()
        })

        welcomer.send({embeds:[welcome]})

        let welcomeRole = guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.id === '954841166933811210');
        console.log(`${user.tag} has joined the server`)
        member.roles.add(welcomeRole);
    }
}
```

I am trying to do create an embed but it is not loading the thumbnail please help me to do it as I am very upset

it did not even give my photo in the embed what is the problem behind it is this is in code or from discord

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow imperial x. i'd like to suggest for you to at least censor your `WebhookClient` `id` and `token`. especially if its a secret stuff for accessing your discord channel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `user.displayAvatarURL()` instead of `user.avatarURL()`